# stsadm -o export with MUI

Tags: 2010, export, stsadm, language

I have a SharePoint 2010 site that I need to export and import on another Web App.  That website has been customized and uses the built in MUI (Multilingual User Interface).

For example : First, I create a List in English with all the columns.  Then I switch SharePoint Display Language to French (in the UserMenu) and rename manually the List and its columns in French. So when I switch language all the identifiers are translated.

When I tried to export/import that site I noticed that all my French translations are gone.  Is there a way to keep those using the stsadm Export/Import method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If this is a publishing site then this link probably won't help you, infact import/export on publishing sites is a nightmare and prone to errors.

[Sharepoint MUI Team Sites](http://www.thesharepointbaker.co.uk/2011/11/sharepoint-mui-team-sites/) (Includes import/export)